# What's a word for the feeling of fulfilling a dream?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to think of a word for the feeling someone gets when they have been working towards achieving a dream, and they finally make it.

Example: Andrew has been working to be signed with the Yankees his whole life, and he finally makes it. What does he feel during his first game?

When they finally get to that stage and they're performing. It's like a feeling of freedom, exhilaration, gratefulness, fulfillment.. one word for it?

Comment: I would say 'consummation' or 'surreal' but I don't think they cover **all** the feelings you have mentioned. Also, they are not the exact fit, somewhat closer to the word you might be looking for.

Comment: "a sense of achievement", "fulfillment", "successful" all seem apt, and contained in your question.

Comment: @PV22: I agree with “fulfillment”. You could also talk around it and say he *realised* his dream, without describing the feeling exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word **jubilance** (and it's related forms) is closer to what I was looking for, though it feels a bit old English.

> **Jubilant**: showing great joy, satisfaction, or triumph; rejoicing; exultant:

[Dictionary.com Definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jubilance)

Answer (score 1):

Elation. Euphoria. Exaltation. Buoyancy. Ebullience/effusiveness.
Any of these help?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to ELU.SE. Perhaps you can take some time to consider the best term in your answer and provide a definition or perhaps an explanation as to why this term is better than the rest?

Answer (score 1):

> **Accomplishment**
> [uh-kom-plish-muh nt]
> /noun
>
> 1. an act or instance of carrying into effect; fulfillment.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/accomplishment)

Comment: This describes the act/fact, but doesn't describe the feeling.

Comment: @ShridharGupta I would disagree. Often, the term accomplishment is used in phrases such as “a feeling of” or “a sense of” accomplishment. I believe your interpretation would refer to the verb form, “to accomplish”. Where as I am citing the noun form.